# PowerQuery Excel vs PowerBI

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Hello PowerQuery experts,

I'm trying to migrate a PowerQuery formula from Power BI PowerQuery to Excel PowerQuery, I was expecting that both PowerQuery implementations were the same but unfortunately, it is either not the case or I fall on some localization issues (French vs English) please found the partial erroneous query and the error message I'm getting in Excel.

```
= Table.Pivot(#"Expanded ""tags"" from Records", 
            List.Distinct(#"Expanded ""tags"" from Records"[name]), "name", "value")


Expression.Error:  Sorry ... We were unable to apply the < operator to the List and List types.
     Details :
     Operator=<
     Left=[List]
     Right=[List]
```

Here the full code excluding APIs Keys pointing to the faultive line:
https://gist.github.com/EricLacroix/e6313e893f3f107f22eccfb79cddadb7#file-gistfile1-txt-L81

Comment: As a general rule: don't use special characters in column/list/step names. That causes more problems than it solves. -- Can you post more of the M code? There is no List involved and no operators either, so it's unclear what the error message is referring to.

Comment: @teylyn Just updated the initial post with the gist, I will look into your suggestion meanwhile

Comment: The operator `<` does not seem to be present in the code you posted at that link

Comment: "don't use special characters in column/list/step names" -- You can put almost anything in a `quoted identifier`, the case where it's not a literal is when you use double quote `"` or contains the escape sequence `#(` -- [Power Query Language Grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-consolidated-grammar#literals)

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

After asking a colleague, we've removed any remaining columns having some complete type being stored in a column before executing the pivot action (e.g.: Records, Arrays) then voilà this fix this issue.